# Regarding double escaping characters when using regexp constructor with a string to make a regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, escaping

In Javascript, I want to match a string pattern that goes something like:

```
\left((some expression here to be matched)\right)
```

It's a little more complicated than that, so I have to define my pattern using the RegExp constructor.  The simplified version is:

```
var pattern_string = '\\left\\((' + EXPRESSIONpattern + ')\\\\right\\)' ;
var pattern_regexp = new RegExp(pattern_string, 'g');
```

I realize that `\r` is the carriage return character in a string, hence having the four back slashes in the pattern_string before the `r`.  Upon implementing, the only way I could get it to work was to also treat `\l` as a special string character and use:

```
var pattern_string = '\\\\left\\((' + EXPRESSIONpattern + '\\\\right\\)' ;
var pattern_regexp = new RegExp(pattern_string, 'g');
```

Why do I need to double escape the `l`?  I can't find a reference that says `\l` is a special string sequence.  What does `\l` mean in a string?   Can someone point me to a reference that includes all characters that need to be double escaped in a string? It would help greatly with debugging to know for sure when I need to double escape.

Thanks in advance for your help,
T

Comment: It is definitely not necessary to do that. I don't know how you tested it, but doubling (quadrupling) the backslash before "l" means to match *two* backslash characters before an "l".

Comment: Also a trick you can use for special letters like "r" is "\\\[r]".

Comment: Means you want to match a literal \ in the text? Then you are right, you would need an escaped backslash (2) in the regex and therefor 4 backslashes in the string defining the regex. This has nothing to do with the "l".

Comment: That is the same than for matching the "\right". you are not matching a carriage return character you are matching the "\" character followed by the "r" character.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The string that the pattern tries to find a match in is like:

`input = '+\\left(\\frac{9^4}{(-8)^{-25}}\\right)';`

I really want to match '+\left(\frac{9^4}{(-8)^{-25}}\right)';` but I've escaped the `\`s.  Do you think escaping the `\`s when I define the input string is the reason? (Really appreciate you taking the time to answer, cheers)

Comment: Thank you stema - I see now.  Much appreciated.  Thanks to all for responding.

Comment: I have had a lot of joy using http://regexr.com to experiment with regexes.

Comment: I find it hilarious that I forgot to escape the `\\`s in my comment above. lol